# EnvDTE and getting constant value from attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

I have a class with constant string routes:

```
public class Routes
{
   public const string Route1 = "api/customers";
}
```

And a WebApi controller class with Route attribute:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
   [Route(Routes.Route1)]
   public IList<Customer> GetCustomers()
   {..}
}
```

I need to get a string value of constant from attribute using **EnvDTE**.

I'm able to receive **CodeAttribute2** object and then value of **CodeAttributeArgument** but its Value just "Routes.Route1".

How to navigate to **Route** type and then to **Route1** constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer (given that you know in advance that the type resides in a file of your project and not in another referenced project or in a compiled reference) is to use EnvDTE.Project.CodeModel and then navigate the code elements recursively (see the approach in [HOWTO: Navigate the code elements of a file from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006008.aspx)) until you find the one with the FullName "<namespace>.Route.Route1", which should be a EnvDTE.CodeVariable, and then use CodeVariable.InitExpression to get the "api/customers" value.

The long answers are:

[How do I get a System.Type from a type name?](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2008/03/06/how-do-i-get-a-system-type-from-a-type-name/)

[How to get a System.Type from an EnvDTE.CodeTypeRef or EnvDTE.CodeClass](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-get-a-system-type-from-an-envdte-codetyperef-or-envdte-codeclass/)